# Hiding an Excel formula untill the fields before are completed

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I'm going crazy here trying to sort the below out.

I am trying to hide the "0" (J9) and the "Yes" (K9) until the dates have been filled in

The Formula in J9 is `=DATEDIF(H13,I13,"d")`
The Formula in K9 is `=IF(J13<=5,"Yes","No")`

```
      H9               I9                 J9                   K9 

Date meter fitted   Date details rec'd  Time to Receive Within 5 days ?
                                           0                   Yes
                                           0                   Yes
                                           0                   Yes
01/03/2014          01/05/2014             61                  No
                                           0                   Yes
                                           0                   Yes
```

If any one can help it would be great!!!

Comment: Dan, when you write a question, there are options to apply formatting. Although it's not obvious, you can use the code option which will render your content more verbatim (although it's not perfect). I've done it for this time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace K9 with:

```
=IF(AND(H13="",I13=""),"",IF(J13<=5,"Yes","No"))
```

So as long as H13 and I13 are empty, nothing will be displayed, otherwise the result of your formula will. Apply the same principle to the other one.

replace J9 with:

```
=IF(AND(H13="",I13=""),"",DATEDIF(H13,I13,"d"))
```

Depending on your particular situation you might have to use OR instead of AND.
Maybe this becomes more understandable, if i write it more like regular program code:

```
IF (H13="" AND I13="")
THEN K9=""
ELSE K9="the result from your formula"
```

Comment: That works perfect for K9, Thank you!!but i cant get it to work for J9....

Comment: You can basically find&replace your formulas, the part for hiding the result while H13 and I13 are empty remains identical.

Answer (score 1):

you can use conditional formatting to make the text white if the input is missing. this has the advantages that it doesn't complicate the formula itself; calculation of the result and whether to show the result are separated

Answer (score 1):

To find the difference in days between two dates a subtraction is sufficient, e.g.

`=I13-H13`

To calculate that only when two dates are present you can use COUNT, i.e.

`=IF(COUNT(H13,I13)=2,I13-H13,"")`